# Dockerfile drupal console access denied mkdir

Tags: docker, drupal, console

I'm trying to install drupal console in docker (under Linux Antergos). I've the following error :

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/drupal/vendor/drupal/console-core/src/Utils/ConfigurationManager.php on line 49

Here is my PHP dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

# Set timezone 
RUN rm /etc/localtime 
RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Bruxelles /etc/localtime 
RUN "date"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        mysql-client \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql mcrypt zip mbstring opcache json

# Install Xdebug / Redis 
RUN pecl install redis \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis xdebug

# Set the Drush version. 
ENV DRUSH_VERSION 8.1.2

# Install Drush 8 with the phar file. 
RUN curl -fsSL -o /usr/local/bin/drush "https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/download/$DRUSH_VERSION/drush.phar" && \   
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drush

# Download console. 
RUN curl https://drupalconsole.com/installer -L -o drupal.phar

# Install console. 
RUN mv drupal.phar /usr/local/bin/drupal && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drupal && \
    drupal init --override

# Create drush-backups dir 
RUN mkdir /var/www/drush-backups/

USER 1000 
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

Comment: what is the docker command you run/build this? i just executed this Dockerfile without any problems so the only thing i can imagine is something like a volume that is not writable

Comment: I use the following command : docker exec -ti CONTAINER_NAME drupal

Comment: Not sure how to help you for me everything works. You can try to do docker exec -i -t {{CONTAINER}} /bin/bash and then run drupal from within the container to see if that makes any diffence. ANd maybe check the rights of drupal console ls -la /usr/local/bin/drupal should be -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 711671 Mar 23 13:19 /usr/local/bin/drupal

Comment: I have the same rights :S

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 711671 Mar 24 08:18 /usr/local/bin/drupal

I continue the investigation. Inside the container, I have the same problem

Comment: Only thing i can think of now is check what user you are with "id -u -n
" (in the docker machine) probbaly you should be www-data. And set your /var/www data to that user "chown -R  www-data:www-data /var/www". The error you get is because console tries to make a .console directory in your home directory which seems to be /var/www when i run it it makes that directory under the www-data:www-data user. Good luck

Comment: Thanks ! I add the following line in my php Dockerfile and it's work. No permissions problem. But now I have this message :
[ERROR] Drupal Console is not installed at:
I can see that many people have the same problem https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues/2751
I continue the investigation. Thanks for your help

Comment: When I try to execute docker exec -i -t docker_php_1 drupal, console ask me to do drupal init again and again. As you said, the problem comes from the path of .console

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I had to install Drupal Console by composer. There is certainly another solution, but it's work with it.